# 2 dimensional array magic square

Tags: c++, arrays

I cannot get this to work.  I need to construct a class named ThreeBy3 that manages a 3 by 3 array of integers.  The class needs to have methods to display its array and determine if the array fits the criteria for a magic square.
 Read 3 x 3 arrays from the below file. For each one read, create an instance of ThreeBy3, then display the array, and follow that with a line of output that states whether the array is a magic square. Don't forget to delete the instance when it is no longer needed.

I am having trouble with the dynamic pointer at the end.  Thank you

This is the code I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <istream>

using namespace std;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::istream;

{
    class ThreeBy3
    {
        static const int SQ = 3;
        static const int rows[][3][2];
        static const int rowCount;
        int square[SQ][SQ];
        int sum;
    public:
        ThreeBy3(int ms[][3]);
        bool isMagicSquare();
        void display(std::ostream& os);
    };

    const int ThreeBy3::rows[][3][2] = {
        { { 0, 0 }, { 0, 1 }, { 0, 2 } },  
        { { 1, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 1, 2 } },
        { { 2, 0 }, { 2, 1 }, { 2, 2 } },
        { { 0, 0 }, { 1, 0 }, { 2, 0 } }, 
        { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 } },
        { { 0, 2 }, { 1, 2 }, { 2, 2 } },
        { { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 2 } },  
        { { 0, 2 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 0 } },
    };

    const int ThreeBy3::rowCount = (sizeof rows) / (sizeof rows[0]);

    bool ThreeBy3::isMagicSquare()
    {


        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            int x = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                x += square[rows[i][j][0]][rows[i][j][1]];
            if (x != sum)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    void ThreeBy3::display(std::ostream& os)
    {
        const int W = 2;
        os << std::setprecision(1) << std::fixed;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                cout << square[i][j] << " ";
            cout<< endl;
        }
    }
}

int main ()
{
    static const int SQ = 3;
    std::ifstream ifs;
    std::string path = "path-to/msq2.txt";
    int iv;
    int ix, jx;
    int ms[3][3] = { { 0 }, { 0 }, { 0 } };
    int rcd = 0;
    ThreeBy3 *msq;
    ifs.open(path);

    if (!ifs)
    {
        cout << "file not found:" << path << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    while (!ifs.eof())
    {
        bool readThreeBy3(std::istream& strm, int ms[][3]);
        {
            int ix, jx, iv;
            for (ix = 0; ix < 3; ++ix)
            {
                for (jx = 0; jx < 3; ++jx)
                {
                    strm >> iv;
                    if (strm.eof())
                        return false;
                    ms[ix][jx] = iv;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        ++rcd;

        if (msq->isMagicSquare())
        {
            cout << "  is a magic square" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "  is NOT a magic square" << endl;
        }
    }
    eof:
    ifs.close();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the file

```
2 7 6
9 5 1
4 3 8

2 9 4
7 1 3
6 5 8

4 3 8
9 5 1
2 7 6

4 9 2
3 7 5
8 1 6

6 1 8
7 5 3
2 9 4

6 7 2
1 5 9
8 3 4

8 1 6
3 5 7
4 9 2

8 3 4
1 6 9
5 7 2
```

Comment: This isn't valid code - it doesn't compile.  For example the function readThreeBy3 is inside another function...  Plus it would be helpful if you said what kind of touble you were having with the dynamic pointer at the end.

Comment: I don't know how to get it to compile is the problem. I don't know where I should be placing that function. Also for the dynamic pointer *msg I don't know why it's not recognized and how I should be declaring it

Answer (score 0):

I changed a couple things:

In C++ you can't have a local function defined inside another function, so I moved that out to global scope.  But then there is no reason to have a free function - if it is a member function that operates on the internal array then we don't need the array in main at all.  So I made it a member function.

One other thing is that you don't need a pointer to ThreeBy3 because there is no reason to dynamically allocate it - it will never live longer than the function it is allocated in anyway.  So I made it a local variable.

Also your loop shouldn't be based on end of file - many other things can cause it finish reading data.  So I have changed it to check for other end conditions as well.

And I removed `using namespace std;` which while useful in a classroom is not good programming practice.

This is how I would change it to get it to go:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <istream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::istream;
using std::ostream;
using std::ifstream;
using std::string;

class ThreeBy3
{
    static const int SQ = 3;
    static const int sum = 15;
    static const int rows[][3][2];
    static const int rowCount;
    int square[SQ][SQ];
public:
    bool isMagicSquare();
    void display(ostream& os);
    bool read(istream& os);
};

const int ThreeBy3::rows[][3][2] = {
    { { 0, 0 }, { 0, 1 }, { 0, 2 } },
    { { 1, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 1, 2 } },
    { { 2, 0 }, { 2, 1 }, { 2, 2 } },
    { { 0, 0 }, { 1, 0 }, { 2, 0 } },
    { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 } },
    { { 0, 2 }, { 1, 2 }, { 2, 2 } },
    { { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 2 } },
    { { 0, 2 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 0 } },
};

const int ThreeBy3::rowCount = (sizeof rows) / (sizeof rows[0]);

bool ThreeBy3::isMagicSquare()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        int x = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < SQ; j++)
            x += square[rows[i][j][0]][rows[i][j][1]];
        if (x != sum)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void ThreeBy3::display(ostream& os)
{
    os << std::setprecision(1) << std::fixed;
    for (int i = 0; i < SQ; ++i)
    {
        os << "\n";
        for (int j = 0; j < SQ; ++j)
            os << square[i][j] << " ";
    }
}

bool ThreeBy3::read(istream& is)
{
    for (int ix = 0; ix < SQ; ++ix)
        for (int jx = 0; jx < SQ; ++jx)
            if (!(is >> square[ix][jx]))
               return false;
    return true;
}

int main ()
{
    string path = "path-to/msq2.txt";
    ifstream ifs;
    ThreeBy3 msq;

    ifs.open(path);

    if (!ifs)
    {
        cout << "file not found:" << path << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    while (msq.read(ifs))
    {
        msq.display(cout);

        if (msq.isMagicSquare())
        {
            cout << "is a magic square" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "is NOT a magic square" << endl;
        }
    }

    ifs.close();
    return 0;
}
```